# Put variable in quotes php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, woocommerce

I want to put variable with product id in quotes of html quotes.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open' ) ) {
    /**
     * Insert the opening anchor tag for products in the loop.
     */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
        global $product;
        $id = $product->get_id();
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );

        echo '<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="$id">';
    }
}
```

`$id` should be in `data-product_id="$id"` but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation requires double quotes.  You're close.

```php
// OLD
echo '<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="$id">';

// NEW
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"yith-wcqv-button\" data-product_id=\"$id\">";
```

Answer (score 2):

We have different ways to do that.

```php
<?php
$id = 321;

// Concatenation operator
echo '<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="' . $id . '">';

// sprintf return a string formatted. It's very common on C code
echo sprintf('<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="%d">', $id);

// heredoc notation
echo  <<<STR
<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="$id">
STR;

// escaping double quotes.
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"yith-wcqv-button\" data-product_id=\"$id\">";
```